# TextBlock width binding to GridView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

On my XAML page I have a text block with following binding:

```
<TextBlock Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SessionList, Mode=OneWay}" ...  />
```

This binds to a grid view:

```
<GridView x:Name="SessionList" ItemsSource="{Binding Sessions}"... />
```

Now when the page first loads and data is available, the text block will be visible and have the correct width. When the page loads and there is no data, the text box will not be visible because of the bound width.

But ... when I load up data in the background and after a while the data comes in (through MVVM) the list will be show, but the text block width will not change accordingly, and setting it as `TwoWay` has no effect.

Any ideas/tips?

Answer (score 0):

ActualWidth is not a property that you can bind to within WinRT. Not sure if you are showing static text or bound text. If bound text and data is same as GridView has then it should go away if data is null. If static data, then use a ValueConverter to set the visibility of the TextBlock based on the data being null/empty

Comment: Hey Shawn, it's not the fact that I want to 'hide' it, that is just a side effect. The text block width has to be the same as the gridview, because the gridview can be wider if there is more data inside it ( horizontal scrolling ) and I want the text block to stretch with it. Like I said above, everything works, if the data of the gridview is available on page load. If, by using MVVM, the data is not available on page load, but comes visible later on, the width of the text block won't change accordingly. So how do I 'set' this dynamically?

Comment: You could subscribe to the SizeChanged event of the GridView and modify the Width of the TextBlock then

Comment: That is indeed a good suggestion! I've currently implemented something similar, shame it doesn't work through direct XAML

Answer (score 0):

Binding issues like this are usually caused by properties that are not bindable, i.e. they are not dependency properties and/or do not implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Whatever. I use a Attached Dependency Property or, if that does not cover enough, a behavior. Now behavior are not included in WinRT, but [that problem has already been addressed](http://winrtbehaviors.codeplex.com/) ;-)